# Text background in a beamer frametitle

Tags: latex, beamer

I am trying to create a beamer presentation with a custom frame title (that is compatible with my organization's corporate design). The text should be in white on a blue background, but the background should be only behind the text (i.e. as if the text was markered). I tried to redefine the frametitle macro using \hl from the soul package, but \hl does not work when it contains the \insertframetitle macro. An approach based on \colorbox is not possible with multiline frametitles. Are there any workarounds?
Greetings!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lua-ul` package (requires lualatex)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\makeatletter
  \newunderlinetype\@myhighLight[\number\dimexpr1ex@%
                               \luaul@currentcolor]{%
    \luaul@applycolor
    \leaders\vrule height 2.25ex depth .75ex
  }
  \NewDocumentCommand\myhighLight{O{\luaul@highlight@color}+m}{{%
    \luaul@setcolor{#1}%
    \@myhighLight#2%
  }}  
\makeatother  

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\myhighLight[frametitle.bg]{\insertframetitle}}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=blue}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Ütitle}
    abc 
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Überraschungsei title title title title title title title title title title title title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but unfortunately the highlighted region is not optimally set - in letters like "Ü", the points over the letter are directly on the border of the colored bar

Comment: @Moritz I asked the author of lua-ul in chat if there is any way to adjust the position, let's see what he says.

Comment: @Moritz Please see my edited answer. The author had the idea to use a custom underline type with a bit taller coloured area.